# Is there a way to get all orders at yobit?

Tags: api

Yobit api says that I have to specify the pair before getting data.

https://yobit.net/en/api/

The problem is that there are so many pairs in yobit. That means I got to call the api several time to get all the pair.

There has to be better way. Is it?

This is the current code

```
   Protected Overrides Function getJson(method As String, otherParameters As Tuple(Of String, String)()) As String
        Dim nonce = exchanges.getNonce().ToString
        Dim content = hashObject("", nonce, "method=" + method + "&nonce=")
        For Each param In otherParameters
            content += "&" + param.Item1 + "=" + param.Item2
        Next
        'content = "method=ActiveOrders&nonce=34697114&pair=html5_btc"
        Dim sighash = computeSig(content)
        Dim result = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://yobit.net/tapi/", content, {Tuple.Create("Key", _apiKey), Tuple.Create("Sign", sighash), Tuple.Create("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")})

        Return result
    End Function
```

Sort of work. It's just that I have a hard time understanding why I should call some API 1000 times to get all orders for my account?

Comment: Having the same issue :(
Their support just ignores my questions

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your requests by calling the `getInfo` endpoint first. Compare the balances in `funds` and `funds_incl_orders` to find currencies with active orders.

Comment: If I am selling A then I own A. But if I am buying A I don't own A yet./

Comment: True, for buy orders you only can pinpoint it to the basecurrency. It still can reduce to 1/6 requests.